# Altium - Custom Pad

Tags: altium

How can I set number to custom made pads for surface mount in Altium? Here the picture

[image]

So it is just shape that I drew on top/bottom solder layer and top/bottom layer. How can I give pin number to those shapes?

Comment: Those are just shapes, not pads. You should create a component footprint with pads using Place->Pad.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Well pads come by default by going throught all layer... How can I change that instead

Comment: Are you trying to draw pads directly on the PCB or in PCB Library?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I am drawing them into the PCB library editor, if there is a way do that, it could be nice to post it. However, I just went and copy/paste a pad from a IPC footprint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you change a pad to SMT single layer:

[image]

This is pretty basic stuff. Altium has excellent documentation- you should work through the tutorials.